React Native (Expo) Xcode build error "Failed to build iOS project. "xcodebuild" exited with error code 70."
I am using React Native with Expo. I want to use React Native Firebase library but it works with native code, that means it doesn't work on Expo Go app, so I need to work on expo-dev-client but I can't do that because Xcode fails when I try to get build.
First, I'm creating /ios and /android folders with:
npx expo prebuild

And then installing pods in /ios folder with:
cd ios && pod install

I can install all pods successfully but it gives a warning at the end like this:
[!] [Codegen] warn: using experimental new codegen integration

And then trying to get a build and start it with:
npx expo run:ios

And then unfortunately, I'm getting these kind of errors:
CommandError: Failed to build iOS project. "xcodebuild" exited with error code 65.

CommandError: Failed to build iOS project. "xcodebuild" exited with error code 70.

Command line invocation:
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace "/Users/saintyusuf/Saint Yusuf/development/personal/dev-client-test/ios/devclienttest.xcworkspace" -configuration Debug -scheme Languist -destination id=50A2477F-DB6A-40E6-99B6-A1EA67F9CDD0

User defaults from command line:

IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Prepare packages

ComputeTargetDependencyGraph

--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:50A2477F-DB6A-40E6-99B6-A1EA67F9CDD0, OS:17.5, name:iPhone 15 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:50A2477F-DB6A-40E6-99B6-A1EA67F9CDD0, OS:17.5, name:iPhone 15 Pro }
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
        PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/saintyusuf/Saint\ Yusuf/development/personal/languist/ios/build/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Codegen.build/Script-46EB2E0002A250.sh (in target 'React-Codegen' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)

2024-06-09 01:36:05.684 xcodebuild[19273:535405] Writing error result bundle to /var/folders/nm/7rwmh19s603d4bbl3mycr_vc0000gn/T/ResultBundle_2024-09-06_01-36-0005.xcresult
xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
                { id:1C57D77C-C9B2-4B6F-95A9-2A583149B1DE }

        Ineligible destinations for the "devclienttest" scheme:
                { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device, error:iOS 17.5 is not installed. To use with Xcode, first download and install the platform }
Build logs written to /Users/saintyusuf/Saint Yusuf/development/personal/dev-client-test/.expo/xcodebuild.log

I was getting different and many more errors when i run the npx expo run:ios command, I searched a lot and found out that if I update Xcode, problems will be solved. So, I updated the Xcode version, those all errors disappeared but now I have a different error.
I updated all npm, node, react, react-native, expo versions but nothing has changed. I'm still getting the same error. So, if there is someone who is already faced with this error, I'm waiting for your help.
By the way, to be sure about if the problem is with my project or any other thing; I created a fresh Expo app with:
npx create-expo-app@latest

I still got the same error when I tried to get a build and run it. I removed Xcode and installed it from scratch, but nothing has changed...
One of my friend suggested me to use bare React Native, not an Expo but I still want to use Expo and its privileges. And I'm wondering, how others can get a build and why I can't? I hope someone can help me and I solve it. Thanks.
